# I have a _ctx.product is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt3 application. And inside a file named ProductList.vue which contains a list of products which returns a name, description, image...
When I try to create a [productId].vue file I get an error _ctx.product is undefined I don't understand why. Thanks for your help

What I tried

ProductList.vue

```
<template>
  <h1 class="mb-4 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 dark:text-white md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl"><span class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r to-blue-600 from-blue-400">Filtrer par catégorie</span></h1>
    <label for="category" class="sr-only"></label>
    <select class="m-2 py-3 px-4 pe-9 block w-full bg-gray-100 border-transparent rounded-lg text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-transparent dark:text-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" v-model="selectedCategory">
      <option class="m-10" value="">Voir tout</option>
      <option v-for="category in uniqueCategories" :key="category" :value="category">
        {{ category }}
      </option>
    </select>
  <ul
    role="list"
    class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8"
  >

    <li
     v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.id"
      class="relative group" data-aos="fade-up">
    
      <NuxtLink :to="'/products/' + product.id">
        <div
          class="absolute top-1 right-1 lg:top-2 lg:right-2 bg-primary group-hover:bg-primaryLighter transition-all w-fit py-1 px-2 rounded-full z-20 scale-90 lg:scale-100"
        >
          <p class="pointer-events-none block text-xs font-medium text-white">
            {{ product.category }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div
          class="aspect-square bg-white flex items-center w-full overflow-hidden rounded-t-lg border"
        >
          <img
          :src="`/images/chateaux/${product.image}`"
            alt=""
            class="pointer-events-none object-contain object-center group-hover:opacity-75 transition-all"
          />
          <button type="button" class="absolute inset-0 focus:outline-none">
            <span class="sr-only">View details for {{ product.title }}</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          class="bg-gray-50 p-3 rounded-b-lg mt-1 border group-hover:bg-gray-100"
        >
          <p
            class="pointer-events-none mt-2 block truncate text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          >
            {{ product.title }}
          </p>
          <p
            class="pointer-events-none block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500"
          >
            {{ product.price }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </NuxtLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCategory: "", // Ajoutez cette propriété
      products: [
      { id: 1, title: 'Candy Land', price: '120€ / jour - 180€ / 2 jours', description:  'loremipsum set', image: 'candy.jpg', category: 'Chateaux Gonflables' },
     { id: 2, title: 'Château Fort', price: '100€ / jour - 160€ / 2 jours', description: 'lorem   ipsum set', image: 'chateau_fort.jpg', category: 'Chateaux Gonflables' },

      ],
   ...
  },
...
</script>
```

[productId].vue

```
<template>
      <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params }) {
      const productId = parseInt(params.productId);
      const product = products.find((p) => p.id === productId);
  
      return { product };
    },
  };
  </script>
```